# Return the subset with smallest cardinality of an array whose elements sum to at least a given value

Tags: algorithms, arrays, subset-sum

Suppose we are given an array $A[1\ldots n]$ and a value $C$.

Is there an algorithm with linear expected runtime that can produce an array that is the subset  with smallest cardinality of $A[1\ldots n]$ whose elements sum to at least $C$?

Comment: What do you mean by “smallest”?

Comment: the subset with the least elements

Comment: I mean, the subset with smallest cardinality

Comment: Have you tried the greedy approach?

Comment: I'm not really sure what the greed approach is

Comment: I suggest spending some time on it, then. Assume the array is given to you sorted.

Comment: Since arrays don’t have “subsets” can you tell exactly what you mean by subset? Being able to ask a precise question is very important.

Comment: If the array was: {1,2,3} a subset of the array would be: {1,2}

Comment: This example isn't very helpful. What are all subsets of this array?

Comment: If the array was [1, 4, 2, 2], would [1, 2] be a subset? What about [1, 2, 2] which is not even a set?

Answer (score 1):

First, we randomly select an element that is not the smallest one as a pivot, and partition the elements into two subsets: the ones less than the pivot ($P$) and the ones no less than the pivot ($Q$). Let $S$ be the sum of elements in $Q$.

- If $S=C$, then $Q$ is exactly the optimal subset we want.
- If $S<C$, then the optimal subset is the union of $Q$ and the subset with smallest cardinality of $P$ whose elements sum to at least $C-S$, which can be found by recursively applying this algorithm on $P$.
- If $S>C$, then the optimal subset is the subset with smallest cardinality of $Q$ whose elements sum to at least $C$, which can be found by recursively applying this algorithm on $Q$.

Let $T(n)$ denote the expected running time of this algorithm on an input of $n$ elements, we have
$$T(n)\le \frac{1}{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} T(\max\{i,n-i\})+cn,$$
where $c$ is a constant. By mathematical induction we can conclude that $T(n)\le 4cn$, thus the algorithm runs in expected linear time.

---

You can also use the idea of [median-of-medians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to get a **worst-case** linear time algorithm by selecting the pivot as the apporximate median produced by the median-of-medians algorithm.